# Using kwargs for handlers functions in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, keyword-argument

This is the example code doesn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def foobar(name, handlerFunction, **handlerArgs):
    handlerFunction(name=name, handlerArgs)


def _doSomething(name, **kwargs):
    print(name)
    print(kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foobar(name='foo', handlerFunction=_doSomething)
    sys.exit()
```

The point here is that `_doSomething` should be exchangeable. And sometimes is has only one argument `name` but sometimes there are more then one.

I got errors like this.

```
  File "./kwargs.py", line 4
    handlerFunction(name=name, handlerArgs)
                                  ^
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Or when I rearange the order of arguments

```
  File "./kwargs.py", line 13, in <module>
    foobar(name='foo', handlerFunction=_doSomething)
  File "./kwargs.py", line 4, in foobar
    handlerFunction(handlerArgs, name=name)
TypeError: _doSomething() got multiple values for argument 'name'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unpack the arguments](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) in the dict, `handlerArgs`, when calling `handlerFunction`:

```
handlerFunction(name=name, **handlerArgs)
```